# Gradle build in Altbeacon library and syntax modification

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I want to do some proximity work with Bluetooth in Android. I have found the Altbeacon library on Github and I understand the principle of detecting distance, but when I was building it with Gradle in Android Studio, it kept returning me error as "Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'.". I also found the tutorials on PubNub but when I copy the syntax in android Studio it still got error (clearly "int mRssi = result.getRssi();" the method ".getRssi" cannot be directly called though I have imported the altbeacon library). I also wondered if there are any tutorials for us to use as a reference because it's a bit hard to understand and use the library just from the examples.

In addition, the problem that we are facing is that we cannot continuously make the phone to scan for the beacons, do we need to create the loop by ourselves or there has existing methods (like scanCallBack) that we can directly call. And I keep finding examples like mScanSettings = mBuilder.build()t (where the mScanSettings is not defined with variable types).
many thanks.

Comment: You should not need a loop actually. When you start monitoring or ranging, it should continue until you stop it. Check this out [link](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) for a reference app and [link](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) for documentation. For more help, please provide related code block so that I can check it out.

Comment: Actually it needs but it seems to be done in a thread with while() loop and with sleep(interval). Anyway thx.

Comment: If you want to set scan rate to get beacons continuously check [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html).

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help you.